# Warning to users who are about to delete their own question and cause question ban

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, post-ban

Given the recent number of users who come here to complain that their account has been suspended because they deleted too many *of their own questions*, could a warning message be added after the first deletion which points to the policy "Your account will be suspended if you delete too many questions"?

Or even a simple: "Are you sure you *need* to delete this questions? [See the FAQ page to learn more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)"

Update: See also the [post-ban](/questions/tagged/post-ban) results for many examples of users who were suspended.

Comment: Here's [one lovely example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97706)

Comment: [And another](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97527)

Comment: [And a slightly older one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86594)

Comment: no need, since those all predate the 30 day fix, see [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91956/i-apparently-got-question-banned-for-deleting-some-of-my-old-zero-upvoted-questi/97720#97720).

Comment: we can also tweak the # of days as necessary if it is still an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That shouldn't be too hard, as it's about the same as notifying users of earned privileges or badges.  Why, though, would you be suspended for deleting your questions?

Comment: That's simple: SE is basically a community wiki...you don't want users to go all rampage on and remove big parts of it (even if it's just their own questions). It's a community driven effort, many people spend a significant part of their life to answer those questions and if they get removed, then this effort is lost. Of course you have the right to do so, but it's very discouraged and on a large scale (user asks question, gets answer, deletes question, repeat) it's a sinkhole for manpower.

Comment: Excessively deleting your own questions is akin to admitting that you've been wasting the time of others who have read and attempted to answer them. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997)