# Hoping Someone Will Review My Edited Question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, post-ban

[This is an edited question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613993/how-to-implement-toolbar-height-binded-to-toolbar-tray-height) on another topic. The first stuff I posted was more to discussion area and I thought SO would be the place for it.

So now I got the booty and banned from asking questions.

I've got a new question that is troubling me, and is codebased, and is not discussion based.

I've googled and searched, and either I can't find any, or I don't understand how to do it.

Perhaps someone here can review it, and see if it's worth reopening or getting my question ban off. I'm just wanting to learn.

Comment: Did you just [take one of your existing questions about machine code and turn it into a question about WPF/XAML in order to get around the question ban](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11613993/revisions)? That's not what I call an "edited question".

Comment: Wait, so you've been banned and are working to get around that by completely changing a question you asked that was closed? I know [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/164454) says to fix your post, but overwriting is not fixing.

Comment: So if i got a new question what do I do? I don't get it.

Comment: You fix your old questions if possible and contribute positively in other areas where you can until you are unbanned. Then and only then can you ask a new question.

Comment: Then I've got a new question that is not discussion based. So I edit the existing one? Or.. ?

Comment: You improve the existing questions you've asked. You don't change their question completely. That is not acceptable and will always be rolled back. If you can improve your question, go ahead. If it requires you to change the question entirely, don't do that.

Comment: Isn't that what you just did?

Comment: I thought if a question is bad, it can be reopened by fixing it. =.=

Comment: Fixing, yes. Completely changing it, no. You've done the latter.

Comment: ok ok. I got it.

Answer (score 6):

You don't fix a car by sending it to the scrapyard and buying a new car. You fix a car by performing in-place repairs on any broken or missing parts so it can start working again. In the same way, you don't fix a question by substituting it with something *completely different*, but you fix it by improving it in ways that allow it to be reopened. What you've done here isn't *fixing* a question, but *replacing* it. These are two different things.

This particular question, though, was closed because it was little more than a trip down memory lane and an open-ended discussion asking about current trends.<sup>1</sup> That's neither a technical problem nor a practical problem, and it was rightfully closed.<sup>2</sup> However you don't just take that question and replace it with something entirely different just because you were question-banned. You're essentially taking a question that could not possibly be reopened and giving it an unfair chance to be reopened.

That said, you have a question here that's still open but received a downvote:

[Beginner in VB.net, lost with DLLs, DirectShow, AVIcap32.dll, and etc For Image Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594722/beginner-in-vb-net-lost-with-dlls-directshow-avicap32-dll-and-etc)

And, IMHO, one that you *can* do something about, since it is at least on topic, unlike the question you're referring to. Perhaps if you could fix that question somehow (and not replace it) and somebody comes along and upvotes it, you'll be able to ask questions again.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>You even added a [discussion-board](/questions/tagged/discussion-board) tag to the question later to indicate that you were starting a discussion, which is **a big no-no on Stack Overflow**. Plus, that tag was meant for questions about discussion board software.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>It didn't help that you reposted the question after it was closed once and insisted that it was constructive and on topic for the site... reposting questions usually never goes well. Although you deleted it yourself later, self-deletions on recent questions count toward the ban as well, much to the [disdain of some](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97711/warning-to-users-who-are-about-to-delete-their-own-question-and-cause-suspension).</sub>

Comment: ok. noted. I'll edit the one I can .