# Allow me to comment on answers

Tags: support, comments, privileges

Someone took a question I posted to the boost-users/spirit-general mailing lists, and [reposted it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074103/how-would-i-perform-this-text-pattern-matching/) on SO. I've been receiving some really good answers, but unfortunately I can't comment on them; instead I need to create a new answer every time I want to comment. Is it possible to enable commenting on my account so I can provide proper feedback on the answers?

Comment: Question being referenced: [How would I perform this text pattern matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074103/how-would-i-perform-this-text-pattern-matching/.)

Comment: No. It's a low bar to earn the comment privilege, If you can't even earn that... ... SO does a good job of blocking and removing clutter, the comment threshold is doing its job.   ...   Also, anyone can *claim* to be the author of an external post.  Our overworked mods have better things to do than to try and verify such "ownership" for someone who wants a special exception.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

To gain this permission, simply answer (correctly or usefully) one question on StackOverflow.  That will be sufficient enough Reputation for you to get the permission you need.  Alternatively, someone can up-vote your question / answer.

The idea is that your answer will be selected as the correct answer (15 Rep) and up-voted by the OP, if the answer was helpful (10 Rep).  Every additional up-vote would be another 10 Rep.

Comment: This in, in fact, incorrect. You need 50 reputation to comment on Stack Overflow. Answering a question provides 0; a single answer upvote provides 10.

Comment: @Brock - However, answering another question doesn't change anything. If what's needed is simply more rep, the existing answers *ought* to be sufficient to get one more upvote. The only way cbroughton's answer makes sense is if it implies that the OP's current answers have no value.

Comment: You guys are just mad that I suggested he post more, which would then in turn be beneficial for both him; and the site in general.

Comment: @cbroughton - Would you care to explain your rationale behind that offensive and entirely unfounded accusation?

Comment: @Dori The down-votes.  Since down-votes (apparently) signify someone dis-agrees with your answer, that would mean they dis-agree that answering a question would be a way for this person to gain enough reputation to comment.  There-in, people whom down-voted were against him answering another question.

Comment: @cbroughton - Given that a quick look at the OP's existing answers shows that they're generally low quality and unhelpful, and that adding additional poor answers doesn't help the OP (or SO in general), and that just adding additional answers does not increase your reputation, perhaps the downvoters believed — with good reason — that you were simply giving incorrect and misleading advice.

Comment: It's not misleading or incorrect to state that poasting more useful answers will give you more reputation.  In my experience, the answers don't even need to be useful, just "correct on some line of thought" for you to get reputation.

Comment: I now have 138 rep, 10 badges, 29 answers and asked 7 questions. Can I get my question-asking privileges back already?

Answer (score 6):

Given the current state of [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074103/how-would-i-perform-this-text-pattern-matching/), my recommendation is:

1. Post a new question—one with the latest updates and a better title.
2. Flag the old question for moderator help, and:

   - Include a link to *this* question.
   - Include a link to your newly-created question.
   - Request that a mod close the older version as a dupe of the newer, and merge the answers from the older to the newer.

IMO, it's *your* question—you should be able to choose which is the accepted answer.

Comment: "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account"

Comment: @A.T. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi

Comment: I've got 8 badges, I've given 23 answers, and I've only asked 15 questions.

Comment: @A.T. - Actually, you've asked 21 questions, but six have been deleted. However, what really matters isn't the number of questions, but the quality. *[Edit: removed link—thought I was linking to a question, but I wasn't.]*

Comment: *answered my last question then. I said 23 (it's 25 now) because that what it said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/587021/a-t)

Comment: @Dori I fear this might set a dangerous precedent. You'll only open up the gates to people claiming some question is theirs (if they have a blog, timestamps can be easily fudged to claim priority in order of events) and request that others be merged into theirs. This also goes against what Jeff has been advocating, which is: "If you find a question in a thread or elsewhere, post it here, get good answers and send the link back to them to show how awesome the site is". I know there is some blog post/meta answer to this effect, but too lazy to search now. I don't think this is the right approach

Comment: @yoda - In general, I agree with you 100%. In this particular case, though, the OP specifically called out that it was someone else's question, and because it came from somewhere else, it went through several ugly iterations. Whatever the mechanism, I'd love to see it turned into a cleaned-up and useful Q&A.

Comment: @Dori sehe seems to be a good contributing member of the community. Since he understands the subject, he surely might be willing to clean up the post and frame it into a more coherent question, if you request. From the deleted posts there, it looks like A.T. is fine with the posting and even asked sehe to post it for him. A.T.'s only issue here is that he couldn't comment on the post. Since he's at 42, I recommend deleting his question w/ -4 votes and doing a recalc. I've already cast mine.  That should net him +8 and take him to 50, which should let him comment.

Comment: @yoda - I hope that it doesn't appear as if I have a problem with sehe's actions, because I don't. And unfortunately, it takes dev access to delete a downvoted question in such a way that it doesn't make things worse for A.T. (or I would have done it already!).

Comment: Don't get me wrong, sehe has been extremely helpful, both with his answers on the mailing-list + stackoverflow and his posting of my question here. The only problem is I can't comment on the answers.

Comment: FYI: My stats now specify 8 Questions : 25 Answers.

Comment: @A.T. - [I wrote earlier](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111986/allow-me-to-comment-on-answers/111990#comment-290558) "it takes dev access to delete a… question in such a way that it doesn't make things worse" I wish you'd read that before deleting your answers, as it did make things worse. Recommended reading: [Should I avoid deleting my questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86982/), [Suspended for deleting old unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97527/), [Question-banned for deleting old, zero-upvoted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91956/).

Comment: "Congrats, you've gained the privilege – comment everywhere" and I got the `scholar badge`. However, this seems to only apply to my meta account, not my other account. Aren't the two linked? - Also, strangely enough, I am only 20% on my way to participating in meta!!!

Comment: @A.T. - [so] and [metase] accounts are not linked. On MSO, you only need one rep to be able to [comment everywhere](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment)—that is, everyone has it (as you can't go below one rep).

Comment: Then what's with the "participate in meta" privilege on my meta account?

Comment: @A.T. - The [Participate In Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/participate-in-meta) privilege's actual name is "Participate in per-site meta." As its description says, it "applies to all per-site Metas except Stack Overflow. You do not need Stack Overflow rep to post on its Meta, and your rep on its Meta isn't tied to the parent site."