# Losing reputation with every question answered

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

I was at 44 reputation 20 minutes ago, but now I am on 38.

So if I want my reputation to increase, should I not answer questions?!

Comment: Note: this is a follow up to [Allow me to comment on answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111986/allow-me-to-comment-on-answers).

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen, this is why this user is complaining: http://stackoverflow.com/users/587021/a-t?tab=reputation&page=1&view=graph

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It isn't a matter of

- **answering questions is good**

  *or*
- **answering questions is bad**

Instead, the breakdown is:

- **answering questions well is good**

  *and*
- **answering questions poorly is bad**

The best way to get out of the ["Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi) pit is to provide *great* answers.

I recommend reading [How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) (and maybe [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), as well).

Comment: This isn't the answer, but since I can't remove my question I am marking it as such before it gets downvoted some more.

Comment: @A.T.: People upvote your question when they think it's a good question and downvote it when they think it's a bad question. If you accept an answer usually doesn't have anything to do with that.

Answer (score 10):

On Stack Overflow? All the [downvotes you've received](https://stackoverflow.com/users/587021/a-t?tab=reputation) appear to be on questions that you've asked.

[Ask better questions](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Comment: Wow, this is a stupid reputation scheme. I just went through that list, the best questions were downvoted. This is not a valid metric for reputation.

Comment: If you say so.[‍](http://www.google.com)

Comment: Because questions like 7806093, 7079316, 7332180 and 5771313 are obviously in need of downvotes...

Comment: Those are pretty off-topic questions for Stack Overflow. That may be part of your problem. We're not a software recommendation service.

Comment: @A.T. - the votes are from your peers on the site, so it isn't the site or system that sucks, it is your questions. Your answers could do with some work as well, out of 25 answers you have just 2 up votes. Dori has given you some good links.